# order of an elliptic curve

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, elliptic-curves

I have found that the curve given by $x^3+x+1=y^2$ over $\mathbb{F_5}$ has 9 points. Now I am supposed to find the number of points of the same curve on $\mathbb{F}_{125}$. Using Hasse and the fact that 9 has to divide this order I have 5 possibilities: $108,117,126,135,144$ but here I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The theory of $L$- and $\zeta$-functions gives the following result (tributed to some combination of Hasse, Weil and Davenport). The number of points on an elliptic curve defined over $\Bbb{F}_q$ can be written in the form
$$
|E(\Bbb{F}_q)|=q+1-\omega_1-\omega_2,
$$
where the complex numbers $\omega_1,\omega_2$ are conjugates of each other, and satisfy $\omega_1\omega_2=q$. Furthermore, for all positive integers $n$ we then have
$$
|E(\Bbb{F}_{q^n})|=q^n+1-\omega_1^n-\omega_2^n.
$$

In your case we have $\omega_1+\omega_2=-3$, and $\omega_1\omega_2=5$. Therefore
$$
\omega_{1,2}=\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{9-20}}2=\frac{-3\pm i\sqrt{11}}2.
$$

The Hasse-Weil-Davenport formula then gives
$$
|E(\Bbb{F}_{125})|=125+1-\omega_1^3-\omega_2^3=108.
$$

Basically knowing $|E(\Bbb{F}_q)|$ fully determines the [Hasse - Weil zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%E2%80%93Weil_zeta_function) of $E$. Then the
[Hasse - Davenport relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%E2%80%93Davenport_relation) govern the way it changes under extensions of fields of constants.

Comment: As a by-product we get that $|E(\Bbb{F}_{25})|=25+1-\omega_1^2-\omega_2^2=27$. This also passes the lithmus tests of the Hasse-Weil bound and divisibilty by $|E(\Bbb{F}_5)|$.

Comment: first of all thank you very much for your answer. I'm not familiar with these omegas, but it looks like to be related with the frobenius endomorphism. could it be related somehow to this?

Comment: The omegas and the theory is explained e.g. in ch.V§2 of Silverman's *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves.* The omegas would be the eigenvalues of the Frobenius map whenever it makes sense - for example in a Tate-module. Thus the trace of the $n$th power of the Frobenius is $\omega_1^n+\omega_2^n$ (again, when you figure out a way for them to make sense). Figuring out the trace of Frobenius (or these eigenvalues) underlies the Schoof-Elkies-Atkin algorithm for calculating the number of points on a given elliptic curve (or, rather their remainders modulo a sequence of primes).

Comment: BTW. Noam D. Elkies roams around in these parts occasionally. With a bit of luck your question may catch his eye, and you may get a more insightful answerw.

Answer (score 4):

I've been sleeping with Silverman and Tate's [Rational Points on Elliptic Curves](http://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/RPECHome.html) under my pillow for years now, with no effect.  So here's the simple country coder's approach.  (Spoiler: yes, 108 points.)

To construct the field $\mathbb{F}_{125}$ we need a cubic irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_5$.  As irreducibility for a cubic amounts merely to the absence of linear factors, and especially as the problem statement already includes $p(X) = X^3+X+1$, we begin by verifying its irreducibility "mod 5":

```
irreduciblePoly :-
    for(X,0,4,1),
    0 is (1 + X*(1+X*X)) mod 5,
    !,
    fail.
irreduciblePoly.
```

This is a Prolog predicate that succeeds if there are no roots (linear factors) modulo 5.  It uses a generator `for/4` of integers specific to Amzi! Prolog, but SWI-Prolog has a similar built-in `between/3` and GNU-Prolog provides both `between/3` and `for/3`.

Since this polynomial passes muster, we implement the field operations `plus/3` and `times/3` in terms of quadratic polynomials that are reductions modulo $p(X)$ and 5.  The addition of field elements is just adding like-coefficients:

```
plus(fElt(A0,A1,A2),fElt(B0,B1,B2),fElt(C0,C1,C2)) :-
    C0 is (A0+B0) mod 5,
    C1 is (A1+B1) mod 5,
    C2 is (A2+B2) mod 5.
```

Multiplication is fancier, but easily derived from $X^3=-X-1$ and $X^4 = -X^2-X$:

```
times(fElt(A0,A1,A2),fElt(B0,B1,B2),fElt(C0,C1,C2)) :-
    C0 is (A0*B0 - A2*B1 - A1*B2) mod 5,
    C1 is (A1*B0 + A0*B1 - A2*B1 - A1*B2 - A2*B2) mod 5,
    C2 is (A2*B0 + A1*B1 + A0*B2 - A2*B2) mod 5.
```

Pinning a note to my sleeve to remember to count the "point at infinity", the plan is to check all the values of $p(X)$ over $\mathbb{F}_{125}$ which are zero (one point on the curve) or which are (nonzero) quadratic residues (two points on the curve):

```
points(125,P,P) :- !.
points(N,P,R) :-
    intoField(N,FElt),
    evalPoly(FElt,Poly),
    increase(Poly,P,Q),
    On is N+1,
    points(On,Q,R).  /* last call */
```

so that we can run the query `?- points(0,1,Pts).`  (The `1` is the point at infinity!)

Here `intoField/2` handily maps integers $0\leq N \leq 124$ into 125 field elements:

```
intoField(N,fElt(A0,A1,A2)) :-
    A0 is N mod 5,
    A1 is (N // 5) mod 5,
    A2 is (N // 25).
```

so that we can evaluate the polynomial for each of them:

```
evalPoly(FElt,Poly) :-
    times(FElt,FElt,FSqr),
    plus(fElt(1,0,0),FSqr,Pm),
    times(FElt,Pm,Pn),
    plus(fElt(1,0,0),Pn,Poly).
```

and adjust the point count accordingly:

```
increase(fElt(0,0,0),P,Q) :- !, Q is P+1.
increase(Poly,P,Q) :-
    quadResidue(Poly),
    !,
    Q is P+2.
increase(_,P,P).
```

I pre-built a "lookup" of quadratic residues `quadResidue/2` by squaring each field element and `assert`'ing it (a Prolog mechanism to create facts dynamically), if not already there:

```
assertQuadraticResidues :-
    for(N,1,124,1),
    intoField(N,FElt),
    times(FElt,FElt,QRes),
    (   quadResidue(QRes)
     -> true
     ;  assert(quadResidue(QRes))
    ),
    fail.
assertQuadraticResidues.
```

Now we can run the code interpretively:

```
?- assertQuadraticResidues.

yes
?- points(0,1,Pts).

Pts = 108 

yes
```

confirming the Answer most elegantly obtained by Jyrki.

Comment: You've convinced me to learn Prolog.