# Diner Combinations, Each Pair Sits Together Exactly Once

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, combinatorial-designs

There are $N^2$ guests at a party. How can we seat these guests at $N$ tables, in a number of rounds, so that each guest sits with every other guest exactly once?

I've come up with an algorithm that works only for prime $N$

In each round, row $i$ consists of the "diagonal elements" stemming from the first element of row $i$ in the previous round. After N rounds, also include the transpose of the original matrix.

This works for $N = 3$

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

1 5 9
4 8 3
7 2 6

1 8 6
4 2 9
7 5 3

1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

But not for $N = 4$

```
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16

 1  6 11 16
 5 10 15  4
 9 14  3  8
13  2  7 12

 1 10  3 12
 5 14  7 16
 9  2 11  4
13  6 15  8

 1 14 11  8
 5  2 15 12
 9  6  3 16
13 10  7  4

 1  5  9 13
 2  6 10 14
 3  7 11 15
 4  8 12 16
```

Note $1$ and $3$ in arrangements 1 and 3

This isn't a homework problem.

Comment: For prime $N$, you've discovered (in a different but equivalent form) the solution: in rounds $r=0,1,\dots,N-1$, take the lines of the form $y=rx+b$ ($0\le b\le N-1$), while in round $N$, take the lines of the form $x=b$ ($0\le b\le N-1$).

Comment: This [can be generalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane#Affine_planes) to cases where $N$ is a prime power, rather than only prime $N$.  It is a famous open problem whether these are the only possibilities.

Comment: I've written a program that performs this algorithm, verifies the result, and prints the permutations, if anyone would like to play around with it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25734046/384954 and yes, I have thought about this problem before answering that SO question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we tackle the general $N^2$ problem, let's [give a solution](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/274891.html) of the $4^2 = 16$ diner problem, grouping them into five courses seated at four tables of four diners each:

First course:

```
X X X X    O O O O    O O O O    O O O O
O O O O    X X X X    O O O O    O O O O
O O O O    O O O O    X X X X    O O O O
O O O O    O O O O    O O O O    X X X X
```

Second course:

```
X O O O    O X O O    O O X O    O O O X
X O O O    O X O O    O O X O    O O O X
X O O O    O X O O    O O X O    O O O X
X O O O    O X O O    O O X O    O O O X
```

Third course:

```
X O O O    O O X O    O X O O    O O O X
O X O O    O O O X    X O O O    O O X O
O O O X    O X O O    O O X O    X O O O
O O X O    X O O O    O O O X    O X O O
```

Fourth course:

```
X O O O    O O O X    O X O O    O O X O
O O X O    O X O O    O O O X    X O O O
O X O O    O O X O    X O O O    O O O X
O O O X    X O O O    O O X O    O X O O
```

Fifth course:

```
X O O O    O X O O    O O X O    O O O X
O O O X    O O X O    O X O O    X O O O
O O X O    O O O X    X O O O    O X O O
O X O O    X O O O    O O O X    O O X O
```

---

The arrangement of $N^2$ diners at $N$ tables through $N+1$ courses of a meal amounts to what in incidence geometry is called [a finite affine plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_plane_(incidence_geometry)).

An affine plane is a system of *points* and *lines* such that:

- Any two distinct points lie on a unique line.
- Each line has at least two points.
- Given a line and point, there is a unique *parallel* line containing the point.
- There exist three non-colinear points (points not all on the same line).

NB: By parallel lines we mean either disjoint or *equal* lines.

The diners are our points, and the $N$-sets of diners served at separate tables during one course are our parallel lines:  each diner is at exactly one of the $N$ tables during a course.

If a line of an affine plane contains $n$ points, we say it is a finite affine plane of order $n$. The following deductions can be made:

- All lines contain $n$ points.
- Every point is contained in $n+1$ lines.
- There are $n^2$ points in all.
- There are a total of $n^2 + n$ lines in all.

In all the known examples of finite affine planes, $n$ is either a prime or a prime power.  A finite affine plane of order $n$ exists if and only if a finite projective plane of order $n$ exists, and thus is equivalent to existence of $n-1$ [mutually orthogonal latin squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeco-Latin_square#Mutually_orthogonal_Latin_squares) of order $n$.

A famous open problem is posed by the conjecture that $n$ not a prime power is impossible.  This [Prime Power Conjecture](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Prime_power_conjecture) remains a topic of active research.

The nonexistence of two orthogonal latin squares of order 6 (Euler/Tarry; see D. Stinson's [A Short Proof...](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009731658490044X) for a modern 4 page treatment) implies there is no finite affine plane of that order, and [Lam's extensive computer investigations](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/organics/papers/lam/) proved there is no finite affine plane of order 10.  Many additional nonexistence results ($n=14,21,22,\ldots$) are shown by [the Bruck-Ryser-Chowla Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruck%E2%80%93Ryser%E2%80%93Chowla_theorem).

The smallest open case is currently order $n=12$.

Linear algebra can be used to construct affine planes or [projective planes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462796/how-do-you-create-projective-plane-out-of-a-finite-field) from finite fields (necessarily of prime power order), and the results are called [Galois geometries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_geometry).  It is known that there are affine planes that are not isomorphic to any of these (but so far only for prime power orders).

**Construction:** Let finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ where $q=p^k$ have a prime power order. Partition the Cartesian product $\mathbb{F}_q\times \mathbb{F}_q$ into $q+1$ families of parallel lines through every pair of distinct points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$.  Each line has $q$ points, so each point will have $q+1 = \frac{q^2-1}{q-1}$ lines through it.  Any $q$ parallel lines must cover the plane, and the required $q+1$ classes of parallel lines are parameterized by their "slope" $s=0,\ldots,q-1,\infty$, where infinite slope means "vertical" lines (first coordinate held constant) and otherwise $s= \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$.

Constructing [the finite field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) of order $q=p^k$ can be done as a quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]/f(X)$ where $f(X)\in \mathbb{Z}_p[X]$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $k$.  I had occasion to construct a finite field of order $5^3=125$ by this method in [this Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905189/order-of-an-elliptic-curve/907011#907011).

Comment: Excellent answer