# Number of points of an elliptic curve

Tags: group-theory, elliptic-curves

In my cryptography course I found the following problem:

Find $|E(\mathbb{F}_{7^{100}})|$ where $E$  is given by $y^2=x^3+1$.

I know how to do it for small numbers, using quadratic residues, but this doesn't work with $7^{100}$. My question is if there is a general method or algorithm that works in general and can be done by hand (no computer) or if there is a clever solution in this particular case.

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you see thngs like $\# E(\Bbb{F}_{7^n})=N(\phi^{7^n}-1) = (\phi^{7^n}-1) ^*(\phi^{7^n}-1)$ already? (Frobenius endomorphism and dual endomorphism) This is detailed in Silverman's AEC.

Comment: @reuns thanks, do you know if we can solve it without strong results? If possible I would like to solve it directlly with elementary methods

Comment: I don't think there is any alternative method.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/905189/11619). I have gotten used to doing it that way because it generalizes to higher genus curves. Knowing the answer for the fields $\Bbb{F}_{p^\ell}$, $\ell=1,2,\ldots,g$, gives you everything. In the case of elliptic curves $\ell=1$ suffices. It is equivalent to using the zeta function as in reuns's comment and WhatsUp's answer.

Comment: Anyway, the theory of zeta functions gives the recipe
$$\#E(\Bbb{F}_{p^n})=p^n+1-\omega_1^n-\omega_2^n$$
for a pair of complex conjugate numbers $\omega_1,\omega_2$ satisfying $|\omega_{1,2}|=\sqrt p$. Counting also the point at infinity we have $\#E(\Bbb{F}_7)=12$, so $\omega_1\omega_2=7$ and $\omega_1+\omega_2=-4$.
This yields $\omega_{1,2}=-2\pm i\sqrt{3}$. And gives the answer
$$\#E(\Bbb{F}_{7^{100}})=7^{100}+1-\omega_1^{100}-\omega_2^{100}=3234476509624757991344647769100216810857205479048020383989725994314227
883581889277376.$$

Comment: I obviously used a computer to calculate that number. The use of zeta functions still makes it simple to find the answer in seconds (most of that time went into me typing in the steps). Brute forcing the variables over the field of $7^{100}$ elements woulk take forever and then some. Everything up to the final expansion of the hundredth powers can be done by hand.

Comment: For this particular elliptic curve life would be simple if, instead of $q=7^{100}$, you would ask for the number of points over $\Bbb{F}_q$ such that $3\nmid q-1$. For in that case cubing in the field is bijective, implying that to each $y$ there is a unique $x$, and hence a total of $q+1$ points.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The zeta function for $E/\Bbb F_p$ is, by definition, the formal power series $$Z(T) = \exp\left(\sum_{r = 1}^\infty \frac{|E(\Bbb F_{p^r})|}rT^r\right).$$
It turns out that $Z(T)$ is a rational function: there exists $a \in \Bbb Z$ such that $$Z(T) = \frac{1 - aT + pT^2}{(1 - T)(1 - pT)}.$$ This result appears e.g. in the book of Silverman, *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, Chapter V, Theorem 2.4 (Page 136).

By calculating $|E(\Bbb F_p)|$, you can determine the value of $a$, which then gives you all the values of $|E(\Bbb F_{p^r})|$.

Comment: One question, is It posible to solve this particular exercise without this general result? Because if It is possible I want to avoid to study all this theory for just one exercise

Comment: I can't see an easier way to do it. I think the number $7^{100}$ is chosen in purpose. For some other choices, there are easier methods. E.g. if it were $p^r$ with $p^r \not\equiv 1\pmod 3$, then we could use the fact that $x \mapsto x^3$ is a bijection from $\Bbb F_{p^r}$ to itself. But this doesn't work for $7^{100}$.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

Let $\,a_n\,$ be the number of solutions to
$\, y^2 \equiv x^3 + 1 \,$ in $\,\mathbb{F}_{7^n}\,$
**and** also the point at infinity.

A search for $\,n=1\,$ yields the $11$ solutions for $\,(x,y)\,$

$$ (0,\pm1),\, (1,\pm3),\, (2,\pm3),\, (3,0),\,
   (4,\pm3),\, (5,0),\, (6,0) $$

in $\,\mathbb{F}_{7}\,$ and thus $\,a_1=12.\,$

The general result (using a constant $\,t_p$) is

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}n T^n = \log{Z(T)}\quad
\text{ where }
\quad Z(T) = \frac{1 + t_pT + p\,T^2}{(1 - T)(1 - p\,T)} $$

as mentioned in another answer. Here $\,t_7=4\,$ and the power series is

$$ Z(T) = 1 + 12T + 96T^2 + 684T^3 + 4800T^4 + 33612T^5 + \cdots. $$

The generating function for $\,a_n\,$ is

$$ A(T) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nT^n = 1 + 12T + 48T^2 + 324T^3 + 
2496T^4 + \cdots. $$

Let $\,b_n := a_n -1\,$ be the number of solutions **not** including
the point at infinity. Then

$$ B(T) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_nT^n = 11T + 47T^2 + 323T^3 + 
2495T^4 + \cdots.$$

Note that $\,b_n\,$ satisfies a linear recursion and has a rational
generating function which is

$$ B(T) = \frac{11 T + 14 T^2 - 49 T^3}
{(1 - 7 T) (1 + 4 T + 7 T^2)}. $$

The result (in general) is that

$$ B(T) = \frac{(p+t_p) T + 2pT^2 -p^2T^3}
{(1 - pT)(1 + t_pT +pT^2)}. $$

And also

$$ b_n = p^n - (\alpha^n + \beta^n) \quad \text{ where } \quad
\alpha\beta = p \text{ and } \alpha+\beta = -t_p. $$

For $\,p=7\,$ the conjugate root constants are
$\,\alpha = -2+i\sqrt{3},\; \beta = -2-i\sqrt{3}.$

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, many thanks

Comment: I haven't gone through the argument, but this answer cannot be correct. In the book of Silverman, *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, Chapter V, Theorem 1.1 (Page 131), it is proved that $|\#E(\Bbb F_q) - q - 1| \leq 2\sqrt q$ (this is in accordance with Weil's conjecture, now a theorem of Deligne). Thus for large $q$, the number of points of $E(\Bbb F_q)$ should be close to $q$. It is impossible that $a_n = 2(7^n - 1)$ for all $n > 0$.

Comment: @WhatsUp I agree with you, but where is the error?

Comment: This sentence: "Now, if $t=x^3$ where $t\neq 0,t\neq −1$ there are two solutions for $y^2=t+1$ ..." There are two solutions only when $t + 1$ is a quadratic residue.

Comment: Your formula produces $a_2 = 2(7^2 - 1) = 98$. The value of $a_2$ should be $48$ (including infinity point).

Comment: @WhatsUp Of course, Again, Thanks for your correction.

Comment: @Marcos After more work I have a correct answer . Thanks for your question.